# Prove that $ S=\left\{ x|\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{p}=1\right\} $ is compact.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $ S=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n|\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{p}=1\right\}  $ .

Where $ p $ is an even positive integer.

I want to prove that this set is compact.

Here's my attempt;

$S $ is bounded, since for example $ S\subseteq B\left(0,n+100\right) $ as for any $ x\in S $, $ x_{i}\leq1$ for $ 1\leq i \leq n $ .

I want to prove now that $ S $ is a closed set.
I'll try to show that $ \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus S $ is an open set.

Let $ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus S $. Define

$ f\left(\delta\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}+\delta\right) $.

Assume without loss of generality that $ f\left(0\right)>1 $. Thus, since $ f $ is a polynomial and hence continuous, there exists $ \varepsilon $ such that for any $ |\delta|<\varepsilon $ we have

$ f\left(\delta\right)>1 $.

Now I want to take small enough $\delta $ such that for any $ x_{0}\in B\left(x,\delta\right) $ I'll get that

$ \left(x_{i}-\delta\right)^{p}\leq\left(x_{0}^{i}\right)^{p}\leq\left(x_{i}+\delta\right)^{p} $.

But Im having trouble with choosing such delta without affecting the inequallity (since p is positive I have to make sure that the inequality holds in case that one of the sides is negative)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can also just show that this is the preimage of $\{1\}$ under $x_1^p + \cdots + x_n^p$, which is a continuous map.

Comment: @Randall Oh, yes, thats a lot easier. Thanks